# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for woocomer api

Tags: react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using an woocommerce rest API for updating customer

When I called the service in postman I am getting the response like this:

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/home/koopi131/public_html/koopicafenet_dev/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-multisite-user-sync/includes/wmus-sync-unsync.php** on line **160**

[image]

Due to the 
 in the starting I am getting an error in my application as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me solving this issue please.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to help if you don't share any code with us, what's in wmus-sync-unsync.php at line 160 ? The error is caused by trying loop over a variable that isn't an array

Comment: Soory but that is not our code we are just using the rest api of woocommerc site